# Div к низу родительского? Без position: absolute!

Tags: css, css3

Есть примерно такой документ:

```
<div .Вообще-Отец>
    <div .Отец>
        <p>Бла бла, какой-то контент

        <div .Спиногрыз>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div .Отец>

        <p>Бла бла, какой-то контент

        <div .Спиногрыз>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Нужно выровнять всех "спиногрызов" к низу "Отцов", но все не так просто. Отцы - flexbox элементы (чтобы имели одинаковую высоту всегда), и когда какому-то отцу привалило богатство в виде дополнительного контента, остальные отцы тоже увеличивают свою высоту и под "спиногрызами" остается свободное пространство - это не красиво.

Позиционирование абсолютное тоже не подойдет, потому что дизайн адаптивен и детишки меняют свою высоту непредсказуемо, т.е. я не знаю каким образом задать отступ снизу, чтобы дети не наползали на контент.
vertical-aling: bottom примененный к спиногрызам, почему-то тоже не дал результата.

Сделать это надо только силами css.

Подскажите, кто знает! Если необходимо, можно и уйти с flexbox на table-cell, без разницы, главное сделать

Вот скрин:[image: скрин]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну например дать "отцам" тоже `display:flex`

```css
.absolute-parent {
  border: 2px solid;
  display: flex;
}

.parent:first-of-type {
  height: 200px;
}

.parent:first-of-type p {
  height: 120px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="absolute-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <p>Бла бла, какой-то контент

      <div class="child">
        дите
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="parent">

    <p>Бла бла, какой-то контент

      <div class="child">
        дите
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, все получилось, спасибо большое!